# After deploying my dynamic rails site on Heroku, the logs showed this Heroku app code=H10 App crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, controller, static

I have no idea why my Heroku App is crashing. This is my first time deploying to Heroku, I followed the steps from my bootcamp in deploying. After, I deployed my I tried running `heroku run rails c, heroku run rails console, heroku run rails test, heroku open, heroku run rails db:migrate, heroku restart`, and I've tried every command in that I could, both on my local computer and heroku(I don't think that really matters, but just more info) `heroku run rails`. However, the interesting command was `heroku run rails c`, because it would tell me `` /app/app/controllers/static_controller.rb:4:in `<class:StaticController>': undefined method `layout' for StaticController:Class (NoMethodError) ``. Which I thought was interesting because in my notes and video, I'm copying literally 100% in the Static_Controller. I've been searching for info why layout would be undefined, however I've come up short after a few hours. I've been running around in circles. If anyone know why my layout would be undefined. I'm up suggestions. This is what my Static_controller looks like

```
class StaticController < Rails::ApplicationController
  layout false

   def index
     render file: Rails.root.join('public', 'index.html')
   end
end
```

P.S. I've added a Procfile & npm init -y(updated scripts)

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client Built'"
  },
...
```

I'm quick to respond.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to be `StaticController < ApplicationController` with the `Rails::` removed.

Comment: Only if `ApplicationController` is defined in this project, it can be also `ActionController::Base`

Comment: @Anthony Payton, does this app even work locally for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your basecamp example seems very funky, hard to tell what freestyling is going on in there. There's seems to be no such thing as `Rails::ApplicationController` (at least in Rails 6, which I have at hand):

I'm checking it using `pry`

```
>> ls Rails
constants: 
  Application       Command        ConsoleMethods  Info            MailersController  Railtie                    VERSION          
  Autoloaders       Configuration  Engine          InfoController  Paths              Secrets                    WelcomeController
  BacktraceCleaner  Console        Html            Initializable   Rack               SourceAnnotationExtractor
```

And trying to reproduce:

```
>> class Foo < Rails::ApplicationController
 |   layout false
 | end  
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::ApplicationController
```

gives me a completely different error.

Make your controller inherit from the "correct" controller class:

```
>> class Foo < ActionController::Base
 |   layout false
 | end  
=> Foo
```

And give it a go.

But, above anything else, you seem to directly deploy stuff to heroku - this will be a painful experience. I'd recommend first focusing on ensuring it runs for you locally `rails sever` command. (Your BootCamp lessons/materials should have started from this point, otherwise, I'd consider this BootCamp fishy... as in - not run by people with reasonable experience to teach others)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: It finally worked not exactly sure why, but thank you for all your help. I definitely used all the advice I got.